# Magento 2 - Product View Report Count

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-view, reports

How does Magento2 count the views of products in the Product Views Report, is it by browser session or per account (login in different accounts using the same browser, each account counts as 1)?

If by browser session, how does Magento defines a browser session? If I open and close a browser within 15 minutes and view a product, will Magento count each session and view as 1?